# Significado dos ícones de membros de classes no Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2013, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2015

Gostaria de saber se existe alguma documentação que trata do significado das imagens/ícones do Visual Studio (obviamente alguns estão explícito (`salvar = disquete`) ou cuja função é mostrada ao posicionar o mouse.)

**Cito como exemplo a imagem abaixo:**

[image: ícones]

> Imagem dos atributos de uma `interface`

Algumas imagens são conhecidos (meu caso) como os `setas = set/get` outros nem tanto como esse `A`

Comment: Já ajuda? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y47ychfe(v=vs.140).aspx

Comment: Ajuda bastante, pena que não exista (eu acho) uma documentação completa referente a este ícones. Obrigado @Maniero

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pra não ficar sem resposta tem [documentação que mostra alguns dos ícones usados](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2015/ide/class-view-and-object-browser-icons?view=vs-2015&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).

Note que eles usam uma técnica de *overlay* colocando mais alguma informação em cima do ícone. No caso o "V" ali indica que o método é virtual. Tem casos que indica a visibilidade do membro, caso do "+" e "*".

Me parece que os demais são sobre controle de versão, mas posso estar enganado.

Talvez a resposta poderia ser melhor com mais contexto.